# Can I have different return types for getter and setter of "valuetype?" properties?

Tags: c#

For example, I have an int? property named Foo, I want the getter to return int?, and the setter to return int(to forbidden null assignment from outside at compile time), which will be like:

```
private int? foo;
public int? Foo {
    get {
        return foo;
    }
}
public int Foo {
    set {
        foo = value;
    }
}
```

The code above will not compile, but I think using accessors this way makes sense. I wonder if C# support such a use case. Otherwise I will have to check if the assigned value is not null in the setter at runtime or work around by adding a pair of method GetFoo and SetFoo.

Comment: What should happen if null is assigned to `Foo`? Usage of accessors make sense but declaring the same variable twice dosen't

Comment: If you want to check it during compile time, you'll have to use a pair method GetFoo and SetFoo.

Comment: It won't compile, since Foo's setter only receives int typed value as its input.

Comment: "No" is the short answer; there are workarounds to support the scenario, but not by having a getter and setter for the same property name but with different types

Comment: The only correct answer to this question is "No, it can't be done". If you want to have workarounds it will quickly dip into "Primarily based on opinion" territory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To only have a property, you can simply write:

```
public int? Foo
{
  get => _Foo;
  set
  {
    if ( !_Foo.Equals(value) )
      _Foo = value.HasValue ? value : throw new NoNullAllowedException();
  }
}
private int? _Foo;
```

Or use a dedicated setter to ensure the not null at compile time as suggested by @SomeBody:

```
public int? Foo => _Foo;
private int? _Foo;

public void SetFoo(int value) => _Foo = value;
```

The majority will prefer this last option.

Also to be homogeneous:

```
private int? _Foo;

public int? GetFoo() => _Foo;
public void SetFoo(int value) => _Foo = value;
```

But if you need to create en entity, to use serialization or some streaming like JSON helpers as well as Visual Studio Designer or runtime Property Editor, or anything requiring a full real read and write property, like ORMs, the first is to be used.

Thus an instance of the class can remove the data of the field from inside, but others artifacts can't set the property to null, just see that it is null.

If child classes can do that, set the field protected.

If other classes in the assembly as well as childs in this assembly can do that, set the field internal.

If other classes in the assembly as well as childs in any assembly can do that, set the field protected internal.

Remark: initial value of _Foo is null.

Comment: "The majority will prefer this last option." . . . I don't prefer a setter method. I know I'm not the majority, but I personally actually think that the majority doesn't prefer such a setter method as well. But that's just a guess, of course. ;) Anyway, perhaps such a setter method would also complicate data binding.

Comment: @BartHofland The first option allows coders to do bad, unclean, and not robust code generating runtime errors and debugging sweats... I exaggerate a little. It must therefore be reserved as explained otherwise it is a waste of time and a source of calamities and disasters since the second option is available.

Comment: Both property setters and setter methods serve the same purpose: encapsulation. They both have their pros and cons. Which encapsulation strategy is chosen should actually depend on functional/technical/logical requirements of the resulting class interface. So your first option is perfectly fine to me as well, if such is required for the class design. (But your property setter example actually does happen to be coded badly indeed. It will throw a `NullReferenceException` when `_Foo` is `null`. But I assume you did so on purpose to demonstrate the dangers.)

Answer (score 1):

No. Different types for the getter and the setter are not possible.

What would you like to do if the setter gets a `null`?

You could either raise an exception:

```cs
public int? Foo
{
    get => _Foo;
    set => _Foo = value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();
}
private int? _Foo;
```

(notice that you can only use `throw` expressions like this in C# 7 and later)

or you could set it to a default value:

```cs
public int? Foo
{
    get => _Foo;
    set => _Foo = value ?? 0;
}
private int? _Foo;
```

Note that inside your class logic, you could still set `_Foo` to `null`. I assume that is desired. Otherwise, there would probably be no point in using type `int?` for the `Foo` property at all and you could just use type `int` for it.

**Edit**

Based on a remark by [Jeppe Stig Nilsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1336654/jeppe-stig-nielsen), I would like to point out that you could also consider to make your `Foo` property of type `int` and introduce a separate boolean field or property to indicate if the `Foo` value is activated/meaningful. It would be a different data model, but for some scenarios it might be a better fit.

```cs
public int Foo { get; set; }
public bool FooIsSet { get; set; }

// Setter method for convenience
public void SetFoo(int? value)
{
    if (value.HasValue)
    {
        this.Foo = value.Value;
        this.FooIsSet = true;
    }
    else
    {
        this.Foo = 0; // optional; you might avoid this line to be able to remember the latest set value
        this.FooIsSet = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Either this, or make an auto-implemented property where the access level of the `set` accessor is restricted, like `public int? Foo { get; private set; }` in combination with _another_ public method or property that only accepts non-null values, for example `public int FooSet { set => Foo = value; }`. This avoids throwing exceptions at people, since they should see at compile-time that they cannot set `Foo` to null.